# Invalid mother's name provided in ESTA application. Do I need to reapply?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Just got my ESTA approved and realised for my parents I've put my mothers maiden name not her married one. Do I need to reapply?

Comment: Oh no - now that they know your mother's maiden name they can access all your online accounts!

Comment: What does it say in her passport?

Comment: Relevant: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61882/i-have-put-the-wrong-information-on-my-esta-application

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your approved ESTA application online for free at [the official DHS website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/.).

If you are issued an ESTA, whether you wish to use it for transit or staying does not appear to be relevant. I don't think it will be a big deal for anyone.