# Invalid purpose of visit marked on the ESTA application. Do I need to reapply?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

When we applied for our ESTA, we incorrectly ticked the TRANSIT box, because we are cruising from one country to another & visiting the U.S. in between. We thought this was the right thing to do. Recently, we have been told that this was wrong. Does this need to be changed and if not,  will it cause us any problems when we get to the US? I have tried to update the information several times but it will not allow me to proceed to 'TRAVEL INFORMATION'-screen.
So I am unable to alter or put in the name of the ship and first port of call in US.

If we applied for another ESTA would the new one override the old one?

Comment: Are ESTAs valid for arrival by cruise ship? I thought they were flight only. Edit: seems I misunderstood "aproved carriers" only, which I guess can include cruise lines

Comment: @CMaster ESTA is for arrival by air or sea.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your approved ESTA application online for free at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/.

If you are issued an ESTA, whether you wish to use it for transit or staying does not appear to be relevant. I do not think it will be a big deal for anyone.

Comment: When you select "Transit" instead of an address, you can after the fact just change your email address you do not have access to any address field to remove the "Transit: Yes" case.